# bazel run *_deploy.jar fails with "cannot execute binary file"

Tags: java, macos, bazel

Given the following `BUILD` file

```
java_library(
  name='target_lib',
  srcs=['target.java',],
)

java_binary(
  name='target',
  runtime_deps=[':target_lib',],
  main_class='com.example.target',
)
```

I can perform a `bazel run //path:target` on a `java_binary` and it successfully executes my application; however when attempting to execute `bazel run //path:target_deploy.jar` it failes with "cannot execute binary file"

I'm attempting this on MacOS (if that matters)

Also if I manually attempt to do a `java -jar bazel-bin/path/target_deploy.jar` I find that the manifest doesn't specify a `main_class`.  Unsure if that's related.

Bazel version information:

```
$ bazel version
Build label: 0.26.1-homebrew
Build target: bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Thu Jun 6 18:36:29 2019 (1559846189)
Build timestamp: 1559846189
Build timestamp as int: 1559846189
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as intended. `bazel run` doesn't actually execute the deploy jar, but a stub script that sets up the runtime environment for the jar determined by the target's dependency graph. If you pass a file label (e.g. `//x/y:deploy.jar`) to `bazel run`, Bazel will attempt to execute it as a standalone binary without `java -jar`.